# ILDASM.exe through Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to find ILDASM.exe from [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008)?

I know the location "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin", but I want it through Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: What do you mean "I want it through vs08"?  What do you mean "any way to find ILDASM.exe"?   It seems like you know where it is, relative to the install path of VS08.  What do you mean by "Find" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "wanting it through Visual Studio", but you can easily add it to the Visual Studio Tools menu with the "Tools `->` External Tools" dialog.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the SDK:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin
```

Personally, though, I'd use [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) instead...

I tend to associate this with bin/exe via the "Open With..." dialog in the [Solution Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Other_tools); add it to that, job done.

Comment: yeah,i do have the SDK and its in the same location mentioned by u .Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET Framework 3.5 that comes with Visual Studio 2008 is more or less only an extension (new assemblies) to .NET 2.0. Therefore the directory structures seem to be different.

On my machine, the new ILDASM.exe is located in **"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin"**.