# Using ILDASM with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll

I just installed Visual Studio 2008, and am looking to use the **Microsoft Intermediate Language Disassembler (`ILDASM.exe`)** to look at some `DLL`s.

Problem is, "`ildasm`" is not recognized on the command line, and I cannot find `ildasm.exe` anywhere in my VS 2008 install directory (e.g. `c:\programs\Visual_Studio_9.0\`).

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Found it!  At `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068193/ildasm-exe-through-vs2008/1068203#1068203) helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's shipped as part of the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E6E1C3DF-A74F-4207-8586-711EBE331CDC&displaylang=en). On my pc, it's at 
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\ildasm.exe`

Comment: gosh... why don't they just put it in the VS directory??

Comment: Because it's not part of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

If you open up the Visual Studio 2008 command prompt, a shortcut to which installed with Visual Studio, then it should be in your path - you can just run it from any directory.